# Send a callable to the hazelcast node which will hold future data

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a Cluster of two hazelcast instances. When I use the executor service and send a task to a key owner where the key is new (means no map contains this key right now, but after the "call") then my callables get distributet to every node.

```
    instance.getExecutorService("default")
            .submitToKeyOwner(callable, newTargetColumn);
```

For debugging purpose I have implemented a EntryListener which just logs the events. There you can see both instances are doing the exact same thing.

```
hz._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-3 TRACE datastore.WorkmapDebugListener - entry added: EntryEvent {worker-map::to be defined} key=high, oldValue=null, value=[1.04, 1.01, 0.98, 0.9, 0.86, 0.83, 0.83, 0.85, 0.92, 0.91, 0.47, 0.49, 0.48, 0.49, 0.48, 0.42, 0.52, 0.56, 0.55, 0.52, 0.53, 0.51, 0.47, 0.49, 0.4, 0.41, 0.39, 0.37, 0.38, 0.37, 0.41, 0.36, 0.38, 0.33, 0.3, 0.31, 0.32], event=ADDED, by Member [192.168.1.157]:5802 this
hz._hzInstance_1_dev.cached.thread-3 TRACE datastore.WorkmapDebugListener - entry added: EntryEvent {worker-map::to be defined} key=high, oldValue=null, value=[1.04, 1.01, 0.98, 0.9, 0.86, 0.83, 0.83, 0.85, 0.92, 0.91, 0.47, 0.49, 0.48, 0.49, 0.48, 0.42, 0.52, 0.56, 0.55, 0.52, 0.53, 0.51, 0.47, 0.49, 0.4, 0.41, 0.39, 0.37, 0.38, 0.37, 0.41, 0.36, 0.38, 0.33, 0.3, 0.31, 0.32], event=ADDED, by Member [192.168.1.157]:5802
```

Is it not possible to get the Node upfront? I mean since the partition will be calculated on the map key anyway?

Can I send a callable to the Node which will probably holding the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'submitToKeyOwner' means that we calculate the hash of that key and find the right member based on that hash. It doesn't matter if a member actually has that key or not. It also doesn't make sense to check for key-existance because which map should we check? Maybe one map has the key and another map hasn't. So there is no dependency on the existence of the key and the routing mechanism used to send that task to a member.

The wrong interpretation here is that of the logging (I was also put on the wrong foot). If you insert a key in some map on member-a, and member-a and member-b have an entry-listener register on that map, BOTH of them will get an event that an entry was added on member-a; even member-b.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask them. Your code should work correctly.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Just as a personal thought: Does it make sense that an EntryListener fires on a Node which is not holding the key? Usually you would do something with the event data and it would be better bringing the work to the data then bringing the data to all listeners in the whole cluster.